# Connect the CSS to the child-theme of wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

My situation is as follows: I have created a child-theme of wordpress with functions.php and the following code (it work):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_theme_style');
function enqueue_parent_theme_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
```

The code for style.css in the theme child I used the following (it work):

```
/*
Theme Name:     Enigma Child
Theme URI:      http://weblizar.com/themes/enigma/
Description:    Tema child per il tema enigma
Author:         Carlo
Author URI:     http://weblizar.com/
Template:       enigma
Version:        2.7
*/
```

For all other CSS for example:

> default.css (father theme)

It is located in the parent theme. How can overwrite the rule by the child-theme

> default.css (chile-theme)

without losing any changes after updating the theme of the father.

Thank you for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could import the parent theme's `default.css` at the top of the child theme's `default.css` then only reference the child's `default.css` in your theme - this means you can then overwrite any rules the parent sets in the child.

```
/* child's default.css */
@import url (" /* path to parent's default.css */ ");
```

Comment: I try this solution, but the Rule sets the child does not overwrite The parent rule. The only css What overwrites the parent rule is style.css. I find to enforce the child theme css rules on those of the parent theme. For example:

" default.css of child-theme overwrite default.css of parent-theme "

Other solutions? Thx

Comment: Take a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqws91xm/). It shows an example of importing a set of css rules (bootstrap in this case - parent default.css in your case) and then overwriting one to change the behaviour - in this instance changing the background colour of `btn-success` from green to red, which you can confirm by removing the `.btn-success` rule in the css panel

Comment: Ok the job I want is precisely this example, but it does not work. Wordpress always considers his parent rule except for the style.css file. The other css as I override them, leaving your css parent theme ?
My situation is
The parent theme (default.css) are this rule:
`.header_section{
 background-color:#31A3DD;
 color:#fff;
} `
The child-theme(default.css) are this rule:
`@import url('../../enigma/css/default.css');

.header_section {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    color: #fff;
}`
what am I doing wrong ? because the theme of the child rule is ignored?
Thx for Answer

Comment: Are you enqueue-ing the parent `default.css` file? You shouldn't be if so. You only need to enqueue the child `default.css`, and use @import within the child one to reference the parent one. Is there a reason you can't use the parent and child `style.css` file instead of `default.css`? The child theme functionality is designed to solve exactly your problem using them.

Comment: I downloaded the Enigma theme and can see the issue now. It stems from the fact that the `style.css` sheet is being called before `wp_head()` in the Enigma theme's `header.php`, thereby meaning that `default.css` is overwriting child customisations. The solution is therefore to create a copy of `header.php` in the child theme, and move the call to `style.css` to under `wp_head()`. I've done this [here](https://github.com/samchivers/enigma-wp-child-theme-demo) for you and have tested that the header_section background appears as red.

Comment: You're a great person. You fixed a bug where I was going crazy. For all the CSS just write the rule in style.css of chile.-theme and he will always overwrite? Thx

Comment: Yes, if you use the revised `header.php` then the `style.css` sheet will always be the last stylesheet loaded. Please mark this as an answer if you're happy with it :)